# Polynomial p(a)=1, why does it have at most 2 integer roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots

Suppose is p(x) is a polynomial with integer coefficients. Show that if p(a)=1 for some integer a then p(x) has at most two integer roots.

I have read the answers given in an earlier post but don't understand why the proof in the answer is complete.

[answer on the other post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybeSS.png)
*If x1,x2,x3 are three distinct integer roots of p, we can write
p(x)=(x−x1)(x−x2)(x−x3)q(x)
and find
1=(a−x1)(a−x2)(a−x3)q(a)
where a−x1,a−x2,a−x3 are pairwise distinct integers and q(a) is a nonzero integer. At most two of a−x1,a−x2,a−x3 can be ∈{±1}.*

My question is, how do you know that q(a) is an integer? Why couldn't q(a) be equal to, say 1/2, and one of the other factors equal to 2, therefore giving other integer solutions?

Comment: First, convince yourself that $q(x)$ has integer coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of various important facts about the integers and integer polynomials. Suppose $p(x)$ has integer coefficients and $p(x_1)=0$ for some integer $x_1$. We can use polynomial division to obtain $$p(x)=(x-x_1)q_1(x)+r_1$$

Now because $x-x_1$ is monic (the coefficient of $x$ is equal to $1$), the division will never result in a non-integer fraction, so that $q_1(x)$ will have integer coefficients, and $r_1$ will be an integer. Setting $x=x_1$ we find that $r_1=0$.

Now $p(x_2)=(x_2-x_1)q_1(x_2)=0$ and since $x_2\neq x_1$ and the integers have no non-trivial zero divisors - they are an integral domain - we must have $q_1(x_2)=0$. Hence $q_1(x)=(x-x_2)q_2(x)$ by the same argument as with $p(x)$ and $q_2(x)$ has integer coefficients.

So when you conclude the argument for the form of $p(x)$ you can conclude that $q(x)$ has integer coefficients.

In later work you will find the notions of "integer" and "monic polynomial" inextricably linked (an algebraic integer satisfies a monic polynomial with integer coefficients). That linking is related to this simple fact about division, and has deeper consequences too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation,